# How to calculate mean of values in the list omitting a special value?

Tags: python, numpy

How to calculate mean of values in the list omitting a special value (-999)?

```
import numpy as np
A = [4,5,7,8,-999]
M = np.mean(A)
```

Any idea ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> np.mean(a)
3.0
>>> np.mean(a[a<=3])
2.0
>>> np.mean(a[a!=4])
2.75
```

For the OP case:

```
np.mean(A[A!=-999])
```

**Performance**

Let's test three snippets: plain `np.mean`, `masked_array` and "naive" solution with Python generators. Array has 1000000 values.

```
from timeit import timeit
setup = 'import numpy as np; a=np.arange(0, 1000000)'
snippets = [
    'assert np.mean(a[a!=999999]) == 499999.0',
    'm=np.ma.masked_array(a,a==999999); assert np.ma.mean(m) == 499999.0',
    'assert sum(x for x in a if x != 999999)/999999 == 499999'
]
timings = [timeit(x, setup=setup, number=10) for x in snippets]
print('\n'.join(str(x) for x in timings))
```

Results:

```
0.0840559005737
0.0890350341797
10.4104599953
```

Plain `np.mean` and `masked_array` have close timings, while "naive" solution is more than 100 times slower.

Comment: thans a lot for speed test, and your idea of np.mean(a[a!=-999])! @alexanderlukanin13

Comment: by the way, how can apply the way of np.mean(a[a!=-999])in the case of multiple arrays, please look at my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835033/how-to-get-mean-of-each-list-inside-the-list-avoiding-certain-value @alexanderlukanin13

Answer (score 3):

In numpy you can use the masked array mean:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([4,5,7,8,-999])
mask_A = A == -999
ma_A = np.ma.masked_array(A, mask_A)
print np.ma.mean(ma_A)
```

Results in:

```
6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know numpy. But this will work

```
A = [4,5,7,8,-999]
A = [item for item in A if item != -999]
print sum(A)/float(len(A))
```

**Output**

```
6.0
```

**Edit:**

To find means of all the sublists,

```
A = [[4,5,7,8,-999],[3,8,5,7,-999]]
M = [sum(z)/float(len(z)) for z in [[x for x in y if x != -999] for y in A]]
print M
```

**Output**

```
[6.0, 5.75]
```

Comment: thanks. but how to calculate mean of values of each list separately inside the list avoiding a special value (-999)?

'A = [[4,5,7,8,-999],[3,8,5,7,-999]]
M = [sum(x)/len(x) for x in [y for y in A if y!= -999]'

Comment: the list comprehensions are fast but even though this solution should be slower than the others, based on masked arrays and fancy indexing...

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import*
A = [4,5,7,8,-999]
result = mean(A[A!=-999])
print (result)
```