# How to get mean of each list inside the list avoiding certain value?

Tags: python, numpy

How to calculate mean of values of each list separately inside the list avoiding a special value (-999)?

```
A = [[4,5,7,8,-999],[3,8,5,7,-999]]
M = [sum(x)/len(x) for x in [y for y in A if y!= -999]
print (M)
```

Any idea ???

For best speed: can someone correct the following code? @alexanderlukanin13

```
M = [np.mean(L [L!=-999])for L in A]
```

Comment: In case your sublists might actually be numpy arrays, you might want to check masked arrays: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> A = [[4,5,7,8,-999],[3,8,5,7,-999]]
>>> M = [np.mean([x for x in L if x > -999]) for L in A]
>>> print M
[6.0, 5.75]
```

**EDIT**

As you mentioned speed as an important requirement, you can do this:

```
>>> B = np.array(A)
>>> np.average(B, axis=1, weights=B!=-999)
array([ 6.  ,  5.75])
```

Everything happens in numpy (i.e. C) space, which should get it pretty fast.

To explain a bit what is happening:

`np.mean(A, axis=1)` and the equivalent `np.average(A, axis=1)` compute the average over the columns of your array, i.e. the vector of means of each row, which is what you want. [`average`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) allows the use of weights: we use `B!=-999`, which is a boolean array, evaluated as `1`s and `0`s when used as weights, i.e. ignoring the values evaluated as `False`.

Answer (score 3):

```
A = [[4,5,7,8,-999],[3,8,5,7,-999]]
M = [sum(z)/float(len(z)) for z in [[x for x in y if x != -999] for y in A]]
print M
```

**Output**

```
[6.0, 5.75]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator function, and no need to create a new list in memory:

```
A = [[4,5,7,8,-999],[3,8,5,7,-999]]
def solve(lis, val):
      for item in lis:
          c = item.count(val)                 #count number of -999 in list
          total = sum(item) - (val*c)         #subtract it from total sum
          yield float(total)/ (len(item) - c) #return mean

print list(solve(A, -999))
#[6.0, 5.75]
```